# How to check postgres user and password?

Tags: postgresql

After concluding installation of postgres I tried to connect using *postgres*, but I don't know the password.

Answer (score 269):

You will not be able to find out the password he chose. However, you may create a new user or set a new password to the existing user.

Usually, you can login as the postgres user:

Open a Terminal and do `sudo su postgres`.
Now, after entering your admin password, you are able to launch `psql` and do

```
CREATE USER yourname WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'yourpassword';
```

This creates a new admin user. If you want to list the existing users, you could also do

```
\du
```

to list all users and then

```
ALTER USER yourusername WITH PASSWORD 'yournewpass';
```

Comment: So I assume it must be done via psql utility but not possible within pgadmin

Comment: @JohnMerlino you can list and create users through phppgadmin, but you won't be able to login if you don't know the password for any account.

Comment: How do you then access this with a URL string?  For example, if you have an app that connects to your database, do you need to enter your username and password in the URL?

Answer (score 13):

You may change the pg_hba.conf and then reload the postgresql.
something in the pg_hba.conf may be like below:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

then you change your user to postgresql, you may login successfully.

```
su postgresql
```